# C++ calling child function from parent class

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ programming and I want to learn about inheritance.  I'm building a software to practice myself with inheritance and I want to know if it is a good design. Here's an extract of my program

```
enum ObjectType{MovingObj, StaticObj};

class WorldObject{
public:
   vector<double> Position;
   WorldObject(ObjectType Type);
};

class MovingObject : public WorldObject {
public:
   double Speed();
   MovingObject(): WorldObject(MovingObj){}
};

class StaticObject: public WorldObject {
public:
   MovingObject(): WorldObject(StaticObj){}
};
```

I have an object World like this

```
class World{
public:
   vector<WorldObject> WorldObjectCollection;
}
```

I have to loop through some code and each loop, I need to update the speed of the moving object and because I need to check collision between moving and static object, I would preferably put all the Object in the same vector.

Is this a good practice to static_cast the WorldObject to the MovingObject base on a switch on the ObjectType ?

Is there a better way to do that? Should I create a virtual Speed() function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you'll have is that your `WorldObjectCollection` vector is a vector of base objects.  Putting `StaticObject` and `MovingObject` in the vector will [slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) them so that only the `WorldObject` part will be stored.  So your `static_cast` will not work at all.

A workable approach would be to have a world `vector<WorldObject*>`.  Using an enum could work, but an approach with polymorphism as you suggest yourself, would be easier to manipulate and maintain. For example, it would be much easier to add new kind of objects as you rgame grows and evolves.